# Groovy RESTClient GET Results Stripping Quotes?

Tags: rest, api, groovy, automation

I am using the Groovy RESTClient for doing some API automation.

The issue I am having is when I am doing a GET call, the results that I get back are missing all the quotes and formatting I would expect. This is making it hard to parse the results.

Example:

What I would expect (and what I am getting back from my API) ...

```
{
    "results": [{
        "licenseType": "mobileAppLicensesWithDevice",
        "name": "Lead Retrieval - Device Rental & App license",
        "owner": {
            "id": "a705c768-ee33-491d-a993-4dd7bc61228b",
            "entityType": "exhibitor"
        },
        "termId": "630493a4-4a70-4f4f-afaf-31610c14c181",
        "id": "c215affe-ed0f-4014-8ba8-53f9df97942a",
        "readableId": "77umkh20kq3",
        "accessCode": "0w7zh6t",
        "updatedAt": "2016-09-22T17:02:06.911Z",
        "createdAt": "2016-09-22T17:02:06.911Z"
    }, {
        "licenseType": "mobileAppLicensesWithDevice",
        "name": "Lead Retrieval - Device Rental & App license",
        "owner": {
            "id": "a705c768-ee33-491d-a993-4dd7bc61228b",
            "entityType": "exhibitor"
        },
        "termId": "630493a4-4a70-4f4f-afaf-31610c14c181",
        "id": "4249aedb-934f-4db1-89d6-6f7f10152bf5",
        "readableId": "fyzv5ay7tfs",
        "accessCode": "ray0pwb",
        "updatedAt": "2016-09-22T17:02:06.911Z",
        "createdAt": "2016-09-22T17:02:06.912Z"
    }, {
        "licenseType": "mobileAppLicensesWithDevice",
        "name": "Lead Retrieval - Device Rental & App license",
        "owner": {
            "id": "a705c768-ee33-491d-a993-4dd7bc61228b",
            "entityType": "exhibitor"
        },
        "termId": "630493a4-4a70-4f4f-afaf-31610c14c181",
        "id": "ea6de933-0043-435c-ad4e-32b81018ec05",
        "readableId": "ytby08d586x",
        "accessCode": "3sv1lj6",
        "updatedAt": "2016-09-22T17:02:06.912Z",
        "createdAt": "2016-09-22T17:02:06.912Z"
    }],
    "etags": [{}, {}, {}],
    "total": 3
}
```

And here is what I am getting back when I use the RESTClient ...

```
{
    etags = [{}, {}, {}], results = [{
        accessCode = wvnc16i,
        createdAt = 2016 - 09 - 23 T15: 08: 20.673 Z,
        id = 06 f7bb76 - cc0c - 450 d - a4af - fcf3392fbd1b,
        licenseType = mobileAppLicensesWithDevice,
        name = Lead Retrieval - Device Rental & App license,
        owner = {
            entityType = exhibitor,
            id = adc7a8e5 - b137 - 40 c6 - 8765 - deb3ce0b8b3f
        },
        readableId = r52jvlr0ok7,
        termId = 630493 a4 - 4 a70 - 4 f4f - afaf - 31610 c14c181,
        updatedAt = 2016 - 09 - 23 T15: 08: 20.673 Z
    }, {
        accessCode = nxf2dzw,
        createdAt = 2016 - 09 - 23 T15: 08: 20.673 Z,
        id = bda7ec58 - 5 c64 - 4082 - 9 da1 - 48534 dd6afcc,
        licenseType = mobileAppLicensesWithDevice,
        name = Lead Retrieval - Device Rental & App license,
        owner = {
            entityType = exhibitor,
            id = adc7a8e5 - b137 - 40 c6 - 8765 - deb3ce0b8b3f
        },
        readableId = b11yew6bqra,
        termId = 630493 a4 - 4 a70 - 4 f4f - afaf - 31610 c14c181,
        updatedAt = 2016 - 09 - 23 T15: 08: 20.673 Z
    }, {
        accessCode = 3e7 f1ip,
        createdAt = 2016 - 09 - 23 T15: 08: 20.674 Z,
        id = 2e12657 a - 8 a62 - 4 d2c - b5d2 - 2 a3fe4c27f9e,
        licenseType = mobileAppLicensesWithDevice,
        name = Lead Retrieval - Device Rental & App license,
        owner = {
            entityType = exhibitor,
            id = adc7a8e5 - b137 - 40 c6 - 8765 - deb3ce0b8b3f
        },
        readableId = ye410zlhqe6,
        termId = 630493 a4 - 4 a70 - 4 f4f - afaf - 31610 c14c181,
        updatedAt = 2016 - 09 - 23 T15: 08: 20.674 Z
    }], total = 3
}
```

*** EDIT ***

Example of the code thats implementing this ...

```
   def getLicenseId(String eventId, String exhibitorId) {
        String licenseId
        def apiGetLicenseId = webClient.get(
                path: "event_api/events/${eventId}/exhibitors/${exhibitorId}/licenses",
                headers: ['Authorization': "api_key $apiKey"],
                requestContentType: JSON
        )
        assert apiGetLicenseId.status == 200 : "API get license ID failed!\nAPI Response: ${apiGetLicenseId.data}"
        String index = apiGetLicenseId.data
        def slurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(index)
        slurper.each {
            println(it)
        }
        licenseId = apiGetLicenseId.data.results[1].id
        println("Index = " + index)
        println("Index Length = " + slurper)
        println("License Id = " + licenseId)
        return licenseId
    }
```

Any thoughts on what the issue is here and how it can be resolved?

Comment: You're going to have to show us how you are making the GET request and how you are receiving the response.

Comment: Looks like it's doing the work for you and returning a map

Comment: Added some sample code of my call.

Comment: @tim_yates I think it could be, however.
How would I go about parsing it to extract information from it based on the key name?

The issue I am having beyond this is I want to loop though the records and extract something like an 'ID' and put it into an array so I can access it in other functions.

Comment: `assert apiGetLicenseId.data.results.accessCode == ['wvnc16i','nxf2dzw','3e7 f1ip']`

Comment: @tim_yates Thats assuming that I know what some of those things are. The actual data I dont know what the values are. Thats what I am trying to capture.

For example `termId` 

How would I find that and store it in a variable and loop though all the JSON objects and extract that and put into an array?

Comment: Errr... `def termIdList = apiGetLicenseId.data.results.termId`

Comment: Ah yes, you are right! I think my brain was fried from trying to figure this out all day. Thanks again @tim_yates